# Workaround to "selectFiles" function call on Flash object

Tags: java, flash, webdriver, swfupload, selenium-webdriver

I'm more of a server-side and javascript programmer. I have never done much with Flash.

I have a robust html form based on flash based swfuploader and I need to test it with Selenium 2 / WebDriver.

The problem is, that

```
movieContent.CallFunction('<invoke name="selectFiles" returntype="javascript">' + __flash__argumentsToXML(argumentArray, 0) + '</invoke>');
```

is not supported in Flash 10 ...

What are we supposed to do ? If it was possible I could `js.executeScript(script);`

But now I have to do some sort of `movieContent.click()` in my java junit/selenium tests but it doesn't trigger the select file window, it doesn't do anything.

It is possible to move the mouse to specified co-ordinates and click using the MoveToOffsetAction, but I didn't manage to do that with FirefoxDriver neither chromeDriver 2.0b3 ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature to prevent a website from accessing the local client side file system. The file system and only be accessed with with a user interaction in the stack trace. IE: a mouse click.

Taking control of the mouse would also be a security violation.

You best bet would be to initiate selenium from the flash function with your onclick event.

This function would first allow you to select the "test" files to upload and then have the function trigger selenium tests.

Comment: As I said, I've never used flash and I'm not going to. I'm using java Webdriver drivers aka selenium 2. I can only initiate tests from my java junit tests. FYI you can take control of your mouse with selenium 2, how is this a security violation when selenium consists in simulating user actions ? Then everything would be a security violation, wouldn't it ?

Comment: The security Violation I was referring to was with flash not selenium. Flash can not control the mouse. Its been a few years since I have used selenium and I did not know it could mimic mouse actions.